# Want to import an STP file to blender with colors

Tags: export, import, file-format

I want to transfer a CAD model to blender. It is in STP format. It has colors applied to it and I want the model along with the colors to be imported to blender. I am using "FreeCAD v0.15" currently to view the STP and to convert to other formats(STL,dae,obj),but unable to export to blender with colors. Anyone know of other methods that can do the job? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

According to FreeCAD's [Key Feature's](http://freecadweb.org/wiki/Feature_list) it looks like you could just export to **OBJ**, **DAE** or **IFC**.

**OBJ** & **DAE** are natively available import options in Blender.

**IFC** does have add-on support in Blender, but from what I can tell it's last compatible version is [2.73 (add-on found here)](http://www.ifcopenshell.org/ifcblender.html). If, howvever, you get the latest from IfcOpenShell's Github repo, they have updated the plugin for Blender 2.80. Blender also now has an IFC exporter which supports recording colour information in IFC format as part of the IfcOpenShell package (v0.6.0 branch).

If these aren't working as expected, then you should be digging further into FreeCAD's export options.

Answer (score 0):

STL files only contain geometry information there is no way to export a STL file with color or texture.

However, if you can find the location the software you are exporting from has the texture file, (if it's a bitmap) you can import the image separately and set it as a blender material texture.